# How does equation numbering work for sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am relatively new to sphinx and I just created two files to test equation cross reference with numbering.

I do the following configuration in conf.py

```
numfig = True
math_numfig = True
numfig_secnum_depth = 2
math_eqref_format = "Eq.{number}"
```

The first file is

```
1. Test File 1 Main
=============

Inline math examples: :math:`\color{blue}{\sigma_{1}}` equals :math:`\colorbox{yellow}{\sigma_{2}}` then etc, etc.

Any text.

.. math::
 x^2+y^2=1
 :label: eq_a

Math block example with label:

.. math::
 e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
 :label: eq_b


1.1 Some Examples
****************

.. math::
 \color{red}{x^2}+y^2=3
 :label: eq_c
```

The second one is

```
2. Test File 2 Main
=============

Refer to :eq:`eq_a`

Refer to :eq:`eq_b`

Refer to :eq:`eq_c`
```

The output is HTML. It does not work for the numbering, all labels are missing (but links are good).

File 1 html output:
[image]

File 2 html output:
[image]

Am I missing something? I am also puzzled how to automatically number the section numbers. The section numbers in the test are manually added. Is it because I need to config section numbers in order for the equation number to appear? What is the right way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: @mzjn I figured out this. I did use a toctree, but I need to add the :numbered: tag. I hope they could have mentioned this in their documentation.

Comment: The toctree documentation says "If you want to have section numbers even in HTML output, give the toplevel toctree a `numbered` option". But great that you figured it out.

Comment: also the [numfig_secnum_depth](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-numfig_secnum_depth) makes some allusion to ``:numbered:``, but yes this is a bit hidden. ([this link for 1.7.x](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-numfig_secnum_depth))

Comment: `:label: ...` for an equation has to go right under the `.. math::` directive, and be followed by a blank line.

Answer (score 6):

As Mad Physicist remarks, answer 3 is wrong. Sphinx does not make a new label when the line with :label: is not directly below '.. math:: like so:

```
.. math::
     :label: eq_a

     e^i + 1 = 0

Which can be referenced in the text using :eq:`eq_a` and so on.
Note the blank lines and the back-tics in the reference. 
Also, there may not be a space between :eq: and `eq_a` in the reference!
Further, no back-tics around the eq_a at the :label: line!
```

I found it a hell of a job to figure this out. So I hope it helps others.

Comment: Yes, `:label:` is an *option* to the `.. math::` directive. Options always come before the content of a directive. See https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#directives. Btw, what do you mean by by "answer 3"?